# Noisy path generated by A* algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, path, noise

I'm working on a front-end for a robotic project (an 'autonomous' car that localizes itself using some sensors and a map - generated from an SVG file).

For the robot to be controllable, we must generate paths between its current position and its goal. I used the easiest algorithm for that : A*.

I got some weird results doing that : The car tends to go on multiples of 45° degree, and one especially annoying problem : some generated paths are quite noisy !

See the noisy path near the orange rectangle in this case :

[image: Vizualisation of the generated path]

Is there anyway to avoid those weird/noisy results ? Eventually we'd want to build a path with the minimum number of heading angle changes. (the car can turn without moving, so we don't need any path 'smoothing').

Here's my A* implementation :

```
def search(self, begin, goal):
    if goal.x not in range(self.width) or goal.y not in range(self.height):
        print "Goal is out of bound"
        return []
    elif not self.grid[begin.y][begin.x].reachable:
        print "Beginning is unreachable"
        return []
    elif not self.grid[goal.y][goal.x].reachable:
        print "Goal is unreachable"
        return []
    else:

        self.cl = set()
        self.ol = set()

        curCell = begin
        self.ol.add(curCell)

        while len(self.ol) > 0:

            # We choose the cell in the open list having the minimum score as our current cell
            curCell = min(self.ol, key = lambda x : x.f)

            # We add the current cell to the closed list
            self.ol.remove(curCell)
            self.cl.add(curCell)

            # We check the cell's (reachable) neighbours :
            neighbours = self.neighbours(curCell)

            for cell in neighbours:
                # If the goal is a neighbour cell :
                if cell == goal:
                    cell.parent = curCell
                    self.path = cell.path()
                    self.display()
                    self.clear()
                    return self.path
                elif cell not in self.cl:
                    # We process the cells that are not in the closed list
                    # (processing <-> calculating the "F" score)
                    cell.process(curCell, goal)

                    self.ol.add(cell)
```

**EDIT 1:** By popuplar demand, here's the score calculation function (process) :

```
def process(self, parent, goal):
    self.parent = parent
    self.g = parent.distance(self)
    self.h = self.manhattanDistance(goal)
    self.f = self.g + self.h
```

**EDIT** Here's the neighbours method (updated following user1884905's answer) :

```
def neighbours(self, cell, radius = 1, unreachables = False, diagonal = True):
    neighbours = set()
    for i in xrange(-radius, radius + 1):
        for j in xrange(-radius, radius + 1):
            x = cell.x + j
            y = cell.y + i
            if 0 <= y < self.height and 0 <= x < self.width and ( self.grid[y][x].reachable or unreachables ) and (diagonal or (x == cell.x or y == cell.y)) :
                neighbours.add(self.grid[y][x])

    return neighbours
```

(this looks complicated but it just gives the 8 neighbours - including diagonal neighbours - of a cell ; it can also take a radius different from 1 because it's used for other features)

And distance calculations (depending on the use of diagonals neighbours or not : )

```
def manhattanDistance(self, cell):
    return abs(self.x - cell.x) + abs(self.y - cell.y)

def diagonalDistance(self, cell):

    xDist = abs(self.x - cell.x)
    yDist = abs(self.y - cell.y)

    if xDist > yDist:
        return 1.4 * yDist + (xDist - yDist)
    else:
        return 1.4 * xDist + (yDist - xDist)
```

Comment: is that an A* or a dijkstra? where's your heuristic part?

Comment: Check out the this [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode) which calls a `heuristic_cost_estimate()` function. Your code doesn't do that so it's not finding the shortest path.

Comment: @GeraldSv : The heuristic I used is "manhattan distance", and it's not actually shown in the code snippet I posted (it's in the 'process' function). I'm gonna post that right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without being able to see how you have implemented your `neighbour` and `distance` functions, I still have a good guess about what is going wrong:

**You should not use manhattan distance if you allow for diagonal traversal.**

The manhattan distance in the goal-function should be a measure of the shortest distance to the goal. (Which it isn't, if you can drive diagonally through building-blocks.)

The easiest way to fix this would be to keep the manhattan distance as a goal-function and change the definition of neighbours to only include the four left-right-up-down adjacent cells.

**Edit**

There are still problems with your code. The following pseudo code is taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm). I have marked important lines that you will have to check. You must ensure that i) you are updating the nodes in the open set if you find a better solution and ii) you always take into account the previously traveled distance.

```
function A*(start,goal)
     closedset := the empty set    // The set of nodes already evaluated.
     openset := {start}    // The set of tentative nodes to be evaluated, initially containing the start node
     came_from := the empty map    // The map of navigated nodes.

     g_score[start] := 0    // Cost from start along best known path.
     // Estimated total cost from start to goal through y.
     f_score[start] := g_score[start] + heuristic_cost_estimate(start, goal)

     while openset is not empty
         current := the node in openset having the lowest f_score[] value
         if current = goal
             return reconstruct_path(came_from, goal)

         remove current from openset
         add current to closedset
         for each neighbor in neighbor_nodes(current)
             // -------------------------------------------------------------------
             // This is the way the tentative_g_score should be calculated.
             // Do you include the current g_score in your calculation parent.distance(self) ?
             tentative_g_score := g_score[current] + dist_between(current,neighbor)
             // ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
             if neighbor in closedset
                 if tentative_g_score >= g_score[neighbor]
                     continue

             // -------------------------------------------------------------------
             // You never make this comparrison
             if neighbor not in openset or tentative_g_score < g_score[neighbor]
             // -------------------------------------------------------------------
                 came_from[neighbor] := current
                 g_score[neighbor] := tentative_g_score
                 f_score[neighbor] := g_score[neighbor] + heuristic_cost_estimate(neighbor, goal)
                 if neighbor not in openset
                     add neighbor to openset

     return failure

 function reconstruct_path(came_from, current_node)
     if current_node in came_from
         p := reconstruct_path(came_from, came_from[current_node])
         return (p + current_node)
     else
         return current_node
```

Comment: I just tried removing the diagonal neighbours and it's true that it removes all the ugly results at the border of obstacles. But the problem now is that there's way too much "aliasing" in paths that should be straight. IS there a way to combine the best of both worls or should I just do some anti-aliasing on the generated path ? Screen shot of the result : http://i.imgur.com/oUr6S4f.jpg
(btw added a 'border' to all obstacles to avoid collision)

Comment: I also tried using a different heuristic (diagonal distance described here : http://rocketmandevelopment.com/2010/11/09/a-star-heuristics/ ) ; it gives way better results than diagonal with manhattanDistance (which all things considered was a stupid thing to do) but I still have some noise and weird results from time to time : http://i.imgur.com/jfEhgmy.jpg

Any ideas ?

Comment: Excellent :-) !

I think the problem comes from the fact that I forgot to do the last part (neighbors not in open set, then comparing the 'g' cost). Also I always thought that "g" represented the cost to move from the parent to the cell, not the whole movement cost.

Now things are way better : http://i.imgur.com/hVic3cX.jpg
Oddly enough, using Manhattan distance instead of diagonal heuristics give shorter paths most of the time : http://imgur.com/z4wJs8b

Comment: @halflings Good that you got it working! The length of the found solution should be minimal. But when there are multiple paths that are equally short it will perhaps not select the optimal path from your point of view, i.e. the smoothest solution with the fewest amount of turns. It will instead follow the boundaries of objects as it is drawn towards the goal as much as possible in each step. This can for example be seen as a bit of a jiggly path that follows the elliptic object near the end of the path (in your first figure).

Answer (score 4):

It seems the implementation is not correct, because it's moving to the *cell not yet in the examined one which is nearest (as the crow flies) to the goal*, while it should *try* it and undo the path when finding an obstacle in order to find the optimal one. See this [nice animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aAstar_progress_animation.gif) on Wikipedia to get the idea.

The issue here is related to how you calculate `cell.f`, maybe you aren't adding the score of the current cell when doing the calculus, in general the A* should take the steps [marked in red here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV2yx.png) and generate sub optimal paths like that.

Since the space is divided into discrete cells, when the best path (always as the crow flies) in a continuous world is right in between two discrete moves, it approximate it as best as it can with that weird path.

I see two approaches here:

1. Fix the algorithm ([here the pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm#Pseudocode)) keeping the correct distance value for each evaluated cell (in the pasted one there's no information about how `cell.f` is calculated).
2. Use **Djikstra**, it should be easy to be implemented with a few changes to the current algorithm. In fact, A* is just an optimized version of it.

Comment: Thank you for the insight ! I added the function calculating cell.f (`process` method) to my original question. ; But I don't see what I'm doing wrong actually. What do you mean by "the path must be undone if you meet an obstacle" ?

Also, I'm open to different algorithms if they can provide less 'angled' paths.

Comment: In my experience, Djikstra is the easiest to implement. Both will give the shortest possible path, so it will not have any unnecessary corner. Now the algorithm iterates until if found an obstacle, then it looks for a new cell, but cannot "undo" the path, thus finding a non-optimal path. I suggest to implement Djikstra,  which is pretty easy to write and can be transformed in an A* (which is a variant of Djikstra) with ease

Comment: *"it's moving to the cell not yet in the examined one which is nearest (as the crow flies) to the goal, while it should try it and undo the path when finding an obstacle in order to find the optimal one"* - this sentence is gibberish.  Could you please explain what you meant by this?  A\* does not do any backtracking.

Comment: True, it doesn't undo the path directly. In the first phase it calculates the topological distance of the cells from the goal and build the tree of paths (using the came_from in wikipedia pseudocode), then it uses this tree to reconstruct the path from source to goal. What I'm saying is that the program needs to keep track of the explored paths, or won't be able to avoid obstacles.

Comment: I still don't understand what's wrong in my implementation. As you can see, I avoid obstacles, I use a heuristic (Manhattan distance) as in the A* pseudo-code you gave me, and find what *looks like* the shortest path. My biggest problem is the "noisy" part that I get sometimes (especially in labyrinths) and the fact that the paths' heading angle is always a multiple of 45° (8 possible directions)

Comment: You avoid obstacle, but what you find is not the optimal (shortest) path, since that is not a correct A* implementation. Think about what will happen when it finds a C-shaped obstacle: it will hit it, then move along new cells until the path "fills" it, eventually avoiding it. TO find the optimal path you need to somehow store what you have tried (not only the single cells, also the paths), in this case with the  `came_from` property of the Wikipedia pseudocode, or with a distinct data structure explicitly storing the path tree

Comment: @Jackopo: That's exactly what I'm doing the 'parent' attribute ! (check the code I posted in the edit). I still can't see what's wrong with my implementation.

Comment: Saw, tried to follow the code step by step but didn't find anything. Have you fixed it? Can you provide a running example?

Comment: Yup, fixed it following "user1884905"'s answer.